# python-mailto create email and show URL as linked text

Tags: python, mailto, python-webbrowser

I currently have

```
import webbrowser
subject = urllib.quote('Some subject')
body = urllib.quote('here is a link: https://www.google.com')
cmd = u'mailto:?subject={}&body={}'.format(subject, body)
webbrowser.open(cmd)
```

This will create an email where the text is

'here is a link: https://www.google.com'

What I want is to show text linked to that url.

'here is a link: [link_text](https://www.google.com)'

Basically how do I achieve the effect of `a href` using `mailto`?